# Compare MySQL entries for 'closest' match

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

(If you saw my previous question, this is part of the same project)

I have no clue on where to start, so I figure why not Google's (and now my) favorite place to look!

I'm building a 'dating' site for a school project (hence the earlier @trnty.edu email verification), and would like to know if it's possible to compare strings for similarities--ergo: "I like long walks on the beach" and "I like taking long walks on the beach, or in the forrest preserves" -- we as people notice the similarities, but I was wondering if there was a way to compare with a percentage of certainty that these *could be* a match.

I don't want to be chasing my tail, so before I continue on with this project, I'd like to know if it were possible first.

Should I be learning PHP, Javascript, Ajax, all of the above(?) for a site like the one specified?

Comment: this might be helpful. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html I haven't used it though, i typically use solr or similar, but that may be out of context for your project.

Comment: This might help. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php In truth though the best way to do it depends on your goals.  I've done something similar for video games but it needed some real thought put into it so that, for instance, every game with "Super" in its title (which is like 90% of Super Nintendo games) wasn't considered similar.

Comment: Interesting example @AndrewNee ,I'll check this out for sure. (Thank goodness it's got an example!)

Answer (score 1):

In a word, "no".

This doesn't mean that what you want to do is impossible, it just means that there are not built-in semantic analyzers that understand the content, context, language, grammar, and intent of text.  Well, these may exist, but they are not commercially available.  And especially not on freeware.

What can you do?  There are several options.  If you are actually looking for similarities of text, two common methods are counting words in common and counting trigrams.  You can google "trigrams" (or n-grams) to see what this means.  Note that both of these will find "I love long walks on the beach" and "I hate long walks on the beach" as being very similar.  To work with word similarity, you will probably need a dictionary and thesaurus, which is one advantage of the n-gram approach.

Another method that gets used, but more for single words or codes, is called Levenshtein Distance (google it ;).  This is a measure of how "different" two strings are based on simple string manipulations.  Once again, though, "I love . . . " and "I hate . . . " are very similar.

To get to the sentiment of text, you then go into sentiment analysis.  This uses dictionaries of what words convey.  The granddaddy of these dictionaries is the Harvard "psycho-social" Dictionary.  At this point, I'm tempted to say that one could write a book on this subject.  I myself have only written one quite long chapter, which is in ***Data Mining Techniques for Marketing, Sales, and Customer Support, Third Edition***.

Comment: (vote up)
I've been looking at 'n-grams' - and they certainly look promising.
Would it be to forward to ask for an 'example' php code -- if I wrote something in English, and extrapolated it for my own purposes? I don't want to leech, but I would like a code 'wing man (or woman)' so to speak. :)

Comment: (Also, I can't vote up until I've got 15 rep, no big, just wanted to let you know)

Comment: Well explained +1. @Sobe - Also done on behalf of you ;)